# Combine (join) networkx Graphs

Tags: python, graph-theory, networkx

Say I have two networkx graphs, `G` and `H`:

```
G=nx.Graph()
fromnodes=[0,1,1,1,1,1,2]
tonodes=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for x,y in zip(fromnodes,tonodes):
    G.add_edge(x,y)

H=nx.Graph()
fromnodes=range(2,8)
tonodes=range(8,14)
for x,y in zip(fromnodes,tonodes):
    H.add_edge(x,y)
```

**What is the best way to join the two networkx graphs?**

I'd like to preserve the node names (note the common nodes, 2 to 7). When I used `nx.disjoint_union(G,H)`, this did not happen:

```
>>> G.nodes()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> H.nodes()
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
>>> Un= nx.disjoint_union(G,H)
>>> Un.nodes()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
#
```

The `H` node labels were changed (not what I want). I want to join the graphs at the nodes with the same number.

*Note. This is not a duplicate of [Combine two weighted graphs in NetworkX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806751/combine-two-weighted-graphs-in-networkx.)*

Comment: What do you want to do if an edge exists in both?  Should it become a double edge? or just a single edge?

Comment: @Joel hmm I'm interested in both cases. Let's say single edge though.

Comment: The single edge case is dealt with okay by the code you've written.  The multiedge case you just do `U=nx.MultiGraph()`

Comment: And a simplification for your example: `for x,y in zip(fromnodes,tonodes):
    G.add_edge(x,y)` can be written `G.add_edges_from(zip(fromnodes,tonodes))`

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [compose](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.compose.html), which produces a graph with all the edges and all the nodes that are in both graphs.  If both graphs have a node with the same name, then a single copy ends up in the new graph. Similarly if the same edge exists in both.  Here's an example, including edge/node attributes:

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1, weight = 2)
G.add_node(2, weight = 3)
G.add_edge(1,2, flux = 5)
G.add_edge(2,4)

H=nx.Graph()
H.add_node(1, weight = 4)
H.add_edge(1,2, flux = 10)
H.add_edge(1,3) 

F = nx.compose(G,H)
#F has all nodes & edges of both graphs, including attributes
#Where the attributes conflict, it uses the attributes of H.

G.nodes(data=True)
> NodeDataView({1: {'weight': 2}, 2: {'weight': 3}, 4: {}})
H.nodes(data=True)
> NodeDataView({1: {'weight': 4}, 2: {}, 3: {}})
F.nodes(data=True)
> NodeDataView({1: {'weight': 4}, 2: {'weight': 3}, 4: {}, 3: {}})

G.edges(data=True)
> EdgeDataView([(1, 2, {'flux': 5}), (2, 4, {})])
H.edges(data=True)
> EdgeDataView([(1, 2, {'flux': 10}), (1, 3, {})])
F.edges(data=True)
EdgeDataView([(1, 2, {'flux': 10}), (1, 3, {}), (2, 4, {})])
```

These preserve attributes, but obviously if there is a conflict this is not possible. The attributes of `H` take precedence.

There are also other options to do the [symmetric difference, intersection](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/operators.html), ...

If you have multiple graphs to join together, you can use [`compose_all`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.all.compose_all.html#networkx.algorithms.operators.all.compose_all), which just wraps a for loop around `compose`.

Comment: How to force all graphs share the same position for nodes with same label when we plot all with `nx.draw_networkx(G) nx.draw_networkx(H) nx.draw_networkx(F) plt.show()`? I mean, coordinates of node `1` should be the same for all 3 graphs.

Comment: @Sigur The plotting commands take an (optional) input `pos` like `nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos)`.  `pos` is a dictionary whose keys are the nodes and whose values are their (x,y) coordinates.  You can define it yourself, or through some of the `layout` commands.  e.g., `pos = nx.spring_layout(F)`.

Comment: I'd like to use the layout first to obtain a good display and then use the same coords when I add new edges and plot again in other window. More or less I'd like to produce a sequence of figures to show a kind of time line for graph.

Comment: @Joel - Awesome answer! Thanks. Do you know if this is possible with graphs of graphs? In my case, some of the nodes are actually graph objects and those graphs contain other nodes (potentially more graphs). The compose function ends up combining everything. I guess this comes down to the hash values or something like that. Just wondering if you have tried this before?

Answer (score 11):

This did it.

```
   U=nx.Graph()
   U.add_edges_from(G.edges()+H.edges())
   U.add_nodes_from(G.nodes()+H.nodes()) #deals with isolated nodes
```

or, preserving the edge attributes:

```
   U.add_edges_from(G.edges(data=True)+H.edges(data=True))
```

and, to also preserve the node attributes:

```
   U.add_nodes_from(G.nodes(data=True)+H.nodes(data=True))
```

Comment: In NetworkX 2.2 G.edges() has to be converted to list before adding. Specially when a MultiGraph is required.

Comment: How does this treat something where I have a graph of like `G: Node1 [label="L1x"], Node2 [label="L2x"]; H: Node1 [label="L1y"], Node2 [label="L2x"]` where Node 1 is meant to be distinct nodes in the joined graph but Node2 is common.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to add graph H to G then return G, you can use [update](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.update.html) method.